# Node.js image convert promise, still get broken image

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am using imagemagick to covert file on node.

```
router.post('/route, upload.array('file'), async (req, res, next) => {
   const files = req.files;
   Promise.all(files.forEach(async (file) =>{
      await fileconvert(file);
   }));

   ...some db create

   return res.send(createdId)
}

//from here different file
import im from 'imagemagick';

function fileconvert(file) {
 return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  if(file.mimetype === "specialcase") {
   im.convert(
    [
     file.path, '-format', 'png', 'newFile.png'
    ],
    (err, stdout) => {
     if(err) reject(err)
     resolve(stdout);
    }
   )
  }
  //if not special-case without this, it doesn't work.
  resolve();
 })
}
```

In front-side, I'm using axios api call.
I am hoping that after fileconvert finished, then res.send(createdId).

Everything works fine, except that if too large file converted, I get broken image.

It may has file on exact directory but it hasn't converted fully yet.

It seems if file created, PASS. How can I get fully converted image...

Process on front-side is "Upload file => if createdId exists => route page

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think it's resolving on first stdout output, which is likely file created successfully

Comment: `await files.forEach` This won't actually await all the promises. You need to use `Promise.all(file.map(...))`

Comment: @laggingreflex Thank you for reply. I changed it although it’s still not working yet.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. You still need to `await Promise.all`

Comment: Also, I see you're still using `forEach`. You need to use `array.map`, and make sure the array is mapped to an array of promises. Checkout the documentation of [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). And ["how to await an array"](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+await+an+array)

Comment: solved with linux imagemagick shell. Thank you.